# Output full string without ellipsis with Pandas and Flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask, tweepy

I am trying to print out the full string for each column in pandas using Flask. More specifically, the tweet_text column is cut short,

This follows the tutorial:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/04/how-to-deploy-machine-learning-model-flask/

I am currently getting the following output.

```
 created_at             tweet_id                                         tweet_text  prediction
0  2020-09-02 13:39:10  1301152689217126403  smh my head at disney every time I think about...           0
1  2020-09-02 13:39:09  1301152689137487872       Tapos parehong may black diko bet kulay nila           1
2  2020-09-02 13:39:09  1301152688898363392  RT @SmokingSkills_: Indian army yesterday only...           0
3  2020-09-02 13:39:09  1301152688286183428  RT @AmonAmarthBand: The longship burst into fl...           0
4  2020-09-02 13:39:09  1301152688202231811  RT @VANTEMETAL: no hate to on but she ain’t bl...           1
```

If I make use of `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)`, the results are even worse.

```
            created_at  ...  prediction
0  2020-09-02 13:50:52  ...           1
1  2020-09-02 13:50:52  ...           0
2  2020-09-02 13:50:52  ...           0
3  2020-09-02 13:50:52  ...           0
4  2020-09-02 13:50:52  ...           0
```

app.py

```
# Flask connection
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from joblib import load
from get_tweets import get_related_tweets

pipeline = load('text_classification.joblib')

def requestResults(name):
    tweets = get_related_tweets(name)
    tweets['prediction'] = pipeline.predict(tweets['tweet_text'])
    data = str(tweets.prediction.value_counts()) + '\n\n'
    return data + str(tweets)

app = Flask(__name__)

# Render default webpage
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

# When post method detected, redirect to success function
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['search']
        return redirect(url_for('success', name=user))

# Get data for requested query
@app.route('/success/<name>')
def success(name):
    return '<xmp>' + str(requestResults(name)) + ' </xmp> '

# Start the Flask server
app.run(debug=True)
```

get_tweets.py

```
# Setup tweepy to access Twitter API
import tweepy
import time
import pandas as pd
#pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)

authentication = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
authentication.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(authentication, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

def get_related_tweets(text_query):
    tweets_list = []
    count = 50
    try:
        for tweet in api.search(q=text_query, count=count):
            print(tweet.text)
            tweets_list.append({'created_at': tweet.created_at,
                                'tweet_id': tweet.id,
                                'tweet_text': tweet.text})
        return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tweets_list)

    except BaseException as e:
        print('failed on_status,', str(e))
        time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the converting a pandas DataFrame to string via str(df) limits the width of each column. Conversion via df.to_string() works without this limitation, hence without the use of ellipsis.

```
def requestResults(name):
    tweets = get_related_tweets(name)
    tweets['prediction'] = pipeline.predict(tweets['tweet_text'])
    data = str(tweets.prediction.value_counts()) + '\n\n'
    return data + tweets.to_string()
```